# sql find and replace

Tags: sql, mysql

So i'm a pretty good systems admin and can manage mysql servers with no issue. My problem is in actually coding sql, and more specifically coding sql I feel safe to automate in nightly scripts. Thats where you awesome stack overflow guys come in.

I currently have my production wordpress site sync to my dev server so we have as close to live for testing on before a push to production. Right after I update the mysql to be a copy of production I need to find and replace about 2,000 strings.

All I need to do is find a way to execute SQL to find and replace http://DrunkOnJudgement.com to http://dev.DrunkOnJudgement.com any place in any table.

Help me Obi wan Kenobis your my only hope.

Comment: How many columns/tables need to be modified, and does this occur in text or as the entire value of a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do something like this

update table_name
set column_name = replace(column_name, 'http://dev.DrunkOnJudgement.com', 'http://DrunkOnJudgement.com');

this will ensure that you simply replace the text you are looking for in a specific column with the text you want it to be without changing any text around it.

so for example you could just shorten it to something like: replace(column_name, 'dev.DrunkOnJudgment.com', 'DrunkOnJudgment.com')

You can also specify a where clause so that you only replace items that contain that text so something like this:

where column_name like '%dev.DrunkOnJudgement.com%'

Ok to do something like this for all columns in all tables, basically search the entire db. You can use a statement like this:

```
SELECT Concat('UPDATE ', TABLE_NAME, ' SET ', COLUMN_NAME, ' = REPLACE(', COLUMN_NAME, ',''dev.DrunkOnJudgment.com'',''DrunkOnJudgment.com'')', ' WHERE ', COLUMN_NAME, ' like ''%dev.DrunkOnJudgment.com%''' ) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

it will output a sql statement like the one above for each column and table in the database and because you are using a replace statement if it does not find the text it does not replace anything it also ensure you only update records that actually contain that text.

So to automate this you would use a cursor, I have not tested the following code but it would look something like this:

```
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE sql VARCHAR(2000);

   DECLARE cmds CURSOR
   FOR
   SELECT Concat('UPDATE ', TABLE_NAME, ' SET ', COLUMN_NAME, ' = REPLACE(', COLUMN_NAME, ',''dev.DrunkOnJudgment.com'',''DrunkOnJudgment.com'')', ' WHERE ', COLUMN_NAME, ' like ''%dev.DrunkOnJudgment.com%''' ) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN;

   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
   OPEN cmds;
   REPEAT
      FETCH cmds INTO sql;
      PREPARE stmt FROM sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DROP PREPARE stmt;
   UNTIL done END REPEAT;
   CLOSE cmds;
```

Comment: This answer can then be repeated on each table for all the columns in that table which could contain that text.

Comment: The issue is we don't know all the table names or the columns. We may add a plugin that has stuff that also needs updated with out us having to update our sync code. Thats the issue we have right now, its a certain plugin that links to our thumbnail images, 1000 of em and hard codes the url rather than just use $siteurl . path or whatever it is. I guess I could use a script to parse each column of each table though.

Comment: Ahhh ok, well then to do something like that you should the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables to loop through each table and column within a cursor. Let me see if I can whip something up real quick.

Answer (score 4):

Is this as simple as an update statement with a where clause?

```
update myTable
set myCol = 'http://dev.DrunkOnJudgement.com'
where myCol = 'http://DrunkOnJudgement.com'
```

Comment: i sincerely doubt that he is going to store _just_ the url in the column, at a minimum it'll be http://example.com/some-page...

Comment: @tobyodavies - I agree, but that's what the OP asked for and he seems to have found an answer that suited his purposes. I didn't fully digest his original question about the any column, any table bit either...seems to be a lesson in question writing and question digesting!

Comment: Even though I didn't select you as the best answer. This was also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in your product's life cycle I guess it is too late to suggest working out a solution that takes away this issue entirely?
For example, not using absolute URLs, or replacing the urls with some variable that is evaluated at runtime?

Comment: Yeah its just a poorly coded wordpress plugin. I shouldn't say poorly coded as it works very well other than the fact they use absolute paths instead of $siteurl . $path